# Google Sign In for python Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I created a project using python in Google App Engine. I want to use google sign in in my website.

I tried to use Google sign In for web and it works well, but I don't know how to make API calls from server to ensure that user is signed in.

I tried to use users ==> user = users.get_current_user()
Then use the user id to make API calls ==>
"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/"+ self.request.get('id') +"?fields=image&key=SOME_KEY"

The problem is that the id is not the one I should use. when I compare this id and the one I get in the javascrip they are not same. Also, in the web API they mentioned that I should ot send that id to server directly (I don't know the reason). So I want to know how can I get the correct id in my python application.

**// Don't send this directly to your server!**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do the docs on backend auth help? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth ... there is an example for decoding an ID token with Python library. Plaintext ID is insecure and could be forged, so you can't use that for backend auth, you need to send and validate an ID token and extract the values from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use user id to make API calls.When you are making API calls to google servers depending on the API you have to pass different parameters.For an example if you want to list down the labels available in you gmail you are going to use the Gmail API and have to pass labelid,userid in the get request. Here is the documentation for above example. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get
You can play around with this API using Try this API box provided by google. Like this example all of the google product has different APIs for different functionalities and you have to pass different parameters according to the documentation they have provided.

Comment: I had to pass an authentication token to backend also to use the API that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

After searching deeply in the google API, I see they introduced a way to send id token instead.
More information can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth